# How to print image out in html, using php echo and $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to print out a users image using PHP and HTML.
The user's image is saved inside the `$_SESSION['usericon']`

The error is on line 3.

I've tried removing the PHP tags and switched print_r out etc.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="img/<?php print_r($_SESSION['userIcon']); ?>">
          <a href="settings.php">Settings</a>
          <form action="lib/logout.php" method="POST">
              <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
          </form>';
} else {
?>
```

Comment: You are in a PHP code section already, so using `<?php` inside of that again makes absolutely no sense. Please go _read up_ on some basics of string concatenation. (We should not have to explain those here, this site is not a replacement for tutorials etc.)

Comment: You could just concat the variable, not sure if this is still the syntax (not done php since v4):  `echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="img/' . $_SESSION['userIcon']) . '">';`

Comment: @executable I have assigned $_SESSION['userIcon'] to a variable but, when i look at the page source now i just do this: <img class="img-responsive" src="img/$userIcon">

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution to your problem. You need to remove the php tags and use [concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="img/'.$_SESSION['userIcon'].'">
          <a href="settings.php">Settings</a>
          <form action="lib/logout.php" method="POST">
              <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
          </form>';
} else {

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="img/<?php print_r($_SESSION['userIcon']); ?>">
```

to

```
 echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="img/'.$_SESSION['userIcon']).'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        $img = sprintf('<img class="img-responsive" src="img/%s" />', $_SESSION['userIcon']);
        echo $img . ' <a href="settings.php">Settings</a>
              <form action="lib/logout.php" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
              </form>';
    } else {
        // @todo
    }
?>
```

rsrs

Answer (score 0):

You have started a PHP code, within a PHP code...
This is the correct img src:

```
src="img/' . print_r($_SESSION['userIcon']) . '"
```

I would suggest you store all (temporary) images on your server, and not in a session file :) Have a nice day.